# Define file name with annotations for xsd file with JAXB/jxc in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jaxb

When I generate my xsd schema file is always called schema1.xsd, how can I set my own name with annotations or?

```
@XmlType(namespace = "http://www.xyz.nu/myname")
@XmlRootElement(name = "myname")
public class Myclass {

int id;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify you xsd file name by defining your `SchemaOutputResolver` as following code shows:

```
public void generate() throws IOException, JAXBException {
  JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(GlobalConfig.class);
  SchemaOutputResolver sor = new MySchemaOutputResolver();
  jaxbContext.generateSchema(sor);
}

private class MySchemaOutputResolver extends SchemaOutputResolver {
  @Override
  public Result createOutput(String namespaceUri, String suggestedFileName) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("your_desired_name.xsd");
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
    result.setSystemId(file.toURI().toURL().toString());
    return result;
  }
}
```

More related:

- [JAXB Problem List](http://tonyz93.blogspot.com/2017/01/jaxb-problem-list.html)